# Prevent an effect running twice in jQuery mouseenter/leave when used with .on()

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown box that operates with the following:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", "#dropdown", function(event){

    if (event.type == 'mouseenter')
        $('#dropdown ul.children').slideDown(1000);
     else
        $('#dropdown ul.children').slideUp(1000);

    //stop();?
});
```

However if you move the mouse out and in fast then you can make another event run before the other has finished, how can I ensure the current on finishes before the next starts?

If I use `.stop()` then it's possible to mouseover and move the mouse back off and on and it will just restart the animation from the beginning making it look jerky?

Comment: You had a pretty good hunch, should have followed through on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", "#dropdown", function(event){

    if (event.type == 'mouseenter')
        $('#dropdown ul.children').stop(true, true).slideDown(1000);
     else
        $('#dropdown ul.children').stop(true, true).slideUp(1000);

});
```

[see jQuery `.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MSmFW/)

Comment: It kind of works ... but if it's slidingUp and you mouse off then mouse on it will start straight from the beginning, can I force it to finish?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you could ignore it completely by using the .not(':animated') within an if/then block. Not sure on the difference in processing time / resource usage  ( http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/ )

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a flag class that signifies the dropdown is being animated. something like this:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", "#dropdown", function(event){

    if (event.type == 'mouseenter')
    {
        $('#dropdown ul.children').addClass("animating");
        $('#dropdown ul.children').slideDown(1000);
        $('#dropdown ul.children').removeClass("animating");
    }
    else
    {
        if ($("#dropdown:not(.animating)")
        {
           $('#dropdown ul.children').slideUp(1000);
        }
         else
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
});
```

or something similar depending on what rules you want to establish for the sliding edge cases.